# convertFromRaw giving this error "Invariant Violation: invalid RawDraftContentState"

Tags: html, json, reactjs, wysiwyg, draftjs

I want to convert html code to draft object to save my editorState
But convertFromRaw function giving me  `Invariant Violation: invalid RawDraftContentState` <- this error.

```
try {
  const htmlToDraftObject = htmlToDraft(
post.content
  );
  console.log(htmlToDraftObject);
  console.log(convertFromRaw(htmlToDraftObject));
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error, "error");
}
```

> console.log(htmlToDraftObject);
>
> this line is returns this object

```
{"contentBlocks":[{"key":"apdo3","type":"unstyled","text":"\"\\n","characterList":[{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null}],"depth":0,"data":{}},{"key":"2lgc","type":"unstyled","text":"","characterList":[],"depth":0,"data":{}},{"key":"118p1","type":"atomic","text":" \\n","characterList":[{"style":[],"entity":"5526de6f-06fd-445d-9ae4-e5bae145adab"},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null}],"depth":0,"data":{}},{"key":"13tke","type":"unstyled","text":"\\n\"","characterList":[{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null}],"depth":0,"data":{}}],"entityMap":{"5526de6f-06fd-445d-9ae4-e5bae145adab":{"type":"IMAGE","mutability":"MUTABLE","data":{"src":"\\\"https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg\\\"","alt":"\\\"undefined\\\"","height":"","width":""}}}}
```

post.content is a simple html code

I tried it without htmlToDraft function too .But it gave me another error

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @purewatashi21 no :(

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519755/how-to-set-initial-editor-state-in-react-draft-wysiwyg

Answer (score 0):

```
{"contentBlocks":[{"key":"apdo3","type":"unstyled","text":"\"\\n","characterList":[{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null}],"depth":0,"data":{}},{"key":"2lgc","type":"unstyled","text":"","characterList":[],"depth":0,"data":{}},{"key":"118p1","type":"atomic","text":" \\n","characterList":[{"style":[],"entity":"5526de6f-06fd-445d-9ae4-e5bae145adab"},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null}],"depth":0,"data":{}},{"key":"13tke","type":"unstyled","text":"\\n\"","characterList":[{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null}],"depth":0,"data":{}}],"entityMap":{"5526de6f-06fd-445d-9ae4-e5bae145adab":{"type":"IMAGE","mutability":"MUTABLE","data":{"src":"\\\"https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg\\\"","alt":"\\\"undefined\\\"","height":"","width":""}}}}
```

change the key `"contentBlocks"` to `"blocks"`

```
{"blocks":[{"key":"apdo3","type":"unstyled","text":"\"\\n","characterList":[{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null}],"depth":0,"data":{}},{"key":"2lgc","type":"unstyled","text":"","characterList":[],"depth":0,"data":{}},{"key":"118p1","type":"atomic","text":" \\n","characterList":[{"style":[],"entity":"5526de6f-06fd-445d-9ae4-e5bae145adab"},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null}],"depth":0,"data":{}},{"key":"13tke","type":"unstyled","text":"\\n\"","characterList":[{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null},{"style":[],"entity":null}],"depth":0,"data":{}}],"entityMap":{"5526de6f-06fd-445d-9ae4-e5bae145adab":{"type":"IMAGE","mutability":"MUTABLE","data":{"src":"\\\"https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg\\\"","alt":"\\\"undefined\\\"","height":"","width":""}}}}
```

This worked for me

[image: console result]