# How to set initial editor state in react draft wysiwyg

Tags: reactjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

While storing the data from react-draft-wysiwyg text editor to server side I convert it to JSON using this function.

```
content = JSON.stringify(
  convertToRaw(state.editorState.getCurrentContent()),
);
```

When I retrieve the data it is in the JSON like this

```
"{\"blocks\":[{\"key\":\"b4n4u\",\"text\":\"Hi \",\"type\":\"unstyled\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":[],\"entityRanges\":[],\"data\":{}},{\"key\":\"bp5jr\",\"text\":\"fgfgfgfgfgfg\",\"type\":\"header-two\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":[{\"offset\":0,\"length\":12,\"style\":\"fontsize-8\"}],\"entityRanges\":[],\"data\":{}},{\"key\":\"81j28\",\"text\":\"\",\"type\":\"unstyled\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":[],\"entityRanges\":[],\"data\":{}},{\"key\":\"1nljr\",\"text\":\"dfdfdf\",\"type\":\"unordered-list-item\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":[{\"offset\":0,\"length\":6,\"style\":\"fontsize-8\"}],\"entityRanges\":[],\"data\":{}},{\"key\":\"b629m\",\"text\":\"dfdfdf\",\"type\":\"unordered-list-item\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":[{\"offset\":0,\"length\":6,\"style\":\"fontsize-8\"}],\"entityRanges\":[],\"data\":{}},{\"key\":\"3afsd\",\"text\":\"dfdfdf\",\"type\":\"unordered-list-item\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":[{\"offset\":0,\"length\":6,\"style\":\"fontsize-8\"}],\"entityRanges\":[],\"data\":{}},{\"key\":\"1rq6j\",\"text\":\"dfdf\",\"type\":\"unordered-list-item\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":[{\"offset\":0,\"length\":4,\"style\":\"fontsize-8\"}],\"entityRanges\":[],\"data\":{}},{\"key\":\"536hu\",\"text\":\"df\",\"type\":\"unordered-list-item\",\"depth\":0,\"inlineStyleRanges\":[{\"offset\":0,\"length\":2,\"style\":\"fontsize-8\"}],\"entityRanges\":[],\"data\":{}}],\"entityMap\":{}}",
```

Now, I want this to be the initialState of editor in another page.

So I tried using defaultEditorState as mentioned in docs https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/docs

```
<Editor
        defaultEditorState={convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(post.content))}
        editorState={state.editorState}
        wrapperClassName='blogpost-text-editor-wrapper'
        editorClassName='blogpost-text-editor'
        toolbarClassName='blogpost-text-editor-toolbar'
        onEditorStateChange={onChange}
      />
```

But it's not working. The [EditorState](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/api-reference-editor-state.html#content) page from draft.js docs is missing so I don't know how to create a EditorState object. Please help me with this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do that. Assuming post.content has ContentState we can initialize EditorState like this.

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(
      convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(post.content)),
    ),
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';
    
const contentBlocks = htmlToDraft(initialState)
const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlocks)
const rawHtml = convertToRaw(contentState)
    
    
<Editor contentState={rawHtml} />
```

Using `htmlToDraft` maintains the style/css of HTML; `convertFromRaw` can cause color loss.